# Python Class - How do I create a class that accepts undefined number of arguments?

Tags: python, class, variables, arguments, init

Im a beginner. For the sake of learning, I have to write a class in python which accepts at most 3 different arguments (a,b,c): something like

```
 class random(object):

     def __init__(self,a,b,c):
          blah blah blah
```

How do I make it so that:

- if no argument is entered, it does one thing.

  for example:

  "test=random()", in this case assume a=b=c=0
- if one argument is entered, it does another thing.

  for example:

  ```
  "test=random(2)", in this case a=2 ,b=c=0, 
   and then run some case specific codes/instrutctions
  ```
- and etc

something like how with the builtin function/class "range", where you can use

range(9)
range(3,9)
range(3,9,2)

if you know what I mean.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're asking about [Default Argument Values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

When defining a function or method, one way to make parameters optional is to give them default values:

```
 def __init__(self, a=0, b=0, c=0):
```

Now, if I call your function (or, in the case of an `__init__` function, construct an instance of your class) with no arguments, `a`, `b`, and `c` will all be 0. If I pass 1 argument, `b` and `c` will be 0. And so on.

See [Arbitrary Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) for another way to do something similar.

---

The way `range` works is a little funky, because the first argument has a different meaning if there's only 1 argument vs. 2 or more. There are a handful of other builtins like this, but it's not a good idea for you to emulate them; these are basically only there for backward compatibility reasons (to the days when Python didn't have keywords).

To make things more fun, because `0` is a perfectly valid value for `start` or `stop`, and so is even `None`, you have to construct some special value that nobody could reasonably pass you. (That part, you may actually need to emulate some day.) So, it looks something like this:

```
class range(object):
    _sentinel = object()
    def __init__(self, start_or_stop, stop=range._sentinel, step=None):
        if stop is range._sentinel:
            start, stop = None, start_or_stop
        else:
            start = start_or_stop
        # Now you can use start, stop, step
```